# is it safe to set access token to redux state for persistent session in React Native?

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm trying to figure out a secure way to persist session in react native.

I have some sensitive data like access token retrieved from server that i'm planning to set to the redux state.

I'm not sure if it is safe to set sensitive data like `accessToken` to redux state.

If not safe, should i save the `accessToken` to device storage like [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) and load the `accessToken` on every screen request and server request?

```
dispatch({type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: {refreshToken, authTimestamp, email} });
```

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {    
    token: {      
        accessToken: '',          
        loading: false,
        error: ''
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, It's safe. But I want to add some comments: I think redux state doesn't store it (unless you use redux-state-persist), means, you will loose the access token when you exit app. In case you want to store it (so user doesn't have to login again), I suggest store it in react-native-keychain, read from it and set to state when app started

Comment: Hi, i have the `refreshToken` and `accessToken` stored in mongoDB, i'm confused if i should store both in the `react-native-keychain`. Or only store `refreshToken` to `react-native-keychain` then load the `accessToken` to redux state.
 The `refreshToken` and `accessToken` are stored in mongoDB.

`newUser.refreshToken = await newUser._id.toString()+ '.' + crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');
                    newUser.accessToken = newUser._id.toString()+ '.' + crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you should be saving the `accessToken` in device secured storage, if you plan on storing it at all. The `refreshTokens` likely should never leave your server as that is possible security vulnerability for the continual generation of new `accessTokens`.

You can load the `accessToken` everytime. Another alternative would be to store the `accessToken` in a secure cookie and pass that back to the app, then you wouldn't have to worry about the management of the tokens at all.

Then there is a question of how you are going to populate that, usually you integrate with an authentication service and an authorization provider. These are two different additional steps to secure your app. I assume you already have off the shelf solutions (if not make a comment and I'll add some examples here)

Comment: Hi, i'm currently following the flow from this guide https://medium.com/@rossbulat/react-native-user-authentication-flow-explained-d988905ba106

Comment: i'm thinking if i should save the `refreshToken(expires in 6months)` to the device storage and use the `refreshToken` to generate an `accessToken(expires in 20mins)`. Both `refreshToken` and `accessToken` will be stored in mongoDB and also device storage. The express server's protected route will compare and check expiration if the `accessToken(expires in 20mins)` in device storage matches the one in user's mongoDB `accessToken`.

Comment: i'm not sure if my approach of having `refreshToken` and `accessToken` is redundant, since it will still need to validate with the server for every request that requires access token validation.

Comment: i'm also looking for a solution to validate tokens securely both on native app and web. For native app, i use `DeviceInfo.getUniqueId()` from `react-native-device-info` npm to check if the user is the owner of the token. For web, it seems like there is no way to get unique device id that does not change. Both IP and MAC address can be altered.

Comment: I will repeat this, the `refresh token` should never be sent to the device.